# Visual Studio 2010 Express 64 bit Properties Missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, 64-bit

I'm trying to run OpenCV with Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2010. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. It seems I have to compile the code (using the OpenCV libraries) as a x64 application. This is fine. I installed the Windows SDK 7.1 that allows you to do this. So now I go to the dropdown menu, configuration manager and select x64 (copying from Win32). But here I run into a problem. I can't seem to edit the properties in this configuration.

If I change back to Win32 and go to project properties I have all the usual options (Configuration Properties -> General, Debugging, VC++ Directories etc.). But in x64 all I have is a practically blank window that has the Common Properties->Framework and References menus. I can't modify anything.

If I try adding a new property sheet in the Property Manger to Debug|x64, I can name and add it, but when I click on it says "There are no property pages for the selection".

I have searched every possible relevant forum for this! Maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms, but I can't seem to find anyone with this exact problem. Am I just missing something about using properties? Or is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use OpenCV 32bit on 64bit OS, make sure your project is 32 bit and make sure Include Directories, Libs, dlls, are correct. Please specify in detail what your problem is.

Comment: Hi,

My problem is I can't actually edit the include directories etc for the x64 project. When I try to access the properties it comes up with an almost blank window. I don't get any of the usual menus (such as General, Debugging, Linker etc.). The properties are all set up for the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ compilers are removed when you upgrade Visual Studio 2010 Professional or Visual Studio 2010 Express to Visual Studio 2010 SP1 if Windows SDK v7.1 is installed. For anyone else who has come across this problem I would recommend updating Visual Studio 2010 SP1 via the below link.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even I faced a problem something similar to this in the start, I am not sure, whether my approach would solve your problem, but, let me give it a try.

After making it x64 as explained in your first step, just click on "ok" and close that window, now, select your project or right click on it, you ll find project properties at the bottom, then use it, you ll find all the available options you need.

when you say, you are seeing "common properties" which means that, you are trying to access the properties of solution not the project, so, select the project before accessing its properties.

your approach of adding a property sheet must work well, go to property manager ->right click on debug/64-> add new property sheet -> name it, save it, you must access it from the next go.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I tried everything in the order you said but I still don't get any modifiable properties. If I right click the solution I get a pretty much blank window that says Framework and References. I was trying to access the properties through the property manager but in that case I only get "There are no property Pages for the Selection" when I try to access the Debug x64 properties.

I think you're right in saying I'm accessing the wrong thing though (such as solution vs project). I just think maybe I'm missing something that still hasn't occurred to me yet!

Answer (score 0):

Just to let anyone know who might be having the same problem, I didn't manage to fix it but I did find a work-around. The latest version of OpenCV (2.4.8 I think) would not compile as a 32 bit application. It gave me an error which apparently means there is a conflict because I have a 64 bit OS. As I stated above, I couldn't get the x64 configuration working correctly. My work-around was to use an older version of OpenCV (2.4.6) and this works fine as a 32 bit application. It has the same functionality. The official OpenCV website has a list of previous versions. Now I have it all working fine!